# How to upgrade libssl-dev to a more recent version?

Tags: 16.04, ssl

Actuallly

```
libssl-dev is already the newest version (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.15).
```

But I need a more recent version to install `ncpa`

```
ncpa : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0f) but it is not installable
```

I am on this system

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

**Can I upgrade libssl-dev? If yes, how?**

EDIT 1: I cannot upgrade an entire server only for a lib

Comment: What do you mean by NCPA? Is it Nagios-related? If yes, then please note - that I have successfully installed [version 2.1.6](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/ncpa/ncpa-2.1.6.amd64.deb) on my clean fully updated Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS amd64.

Comment: Yes, the specific case is for nagios ncpa, but my question is more general applied. In the specific case, anyway, My problem was not the _controller_ but the _remote_ host (the _controlled_ machines). on an old ubuntu 16.04 I cannot install ncpa agent because of this lib too old. But, I repeat, I wanted to post a general problem question because this problem often affects other softwares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [upgrade to 18.04](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_or_17.10). It has [`libssl1.1` version `1.1.0g-2ubuntu4.3`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/libssl1.1) (as the time of writing), which satisfies your dependency.

Comment: Well, I cannot upgrade an entire server only for a lib

Comment: @realtebo Well then, since Ubuntu does not provide the package you need for 16.04, you'll have to create it yourself or hire someone to do it for you. And for such a security-critical package as libssl, this should really be done by someone who knows what they are doing.

Comment: So, is there no 'backports' of this lib?

Comment: @realtebo No, there isn't. Not officially, at least.